# Position absolute ignoring width of parent when use padding

Tags: css

I have 2 divs 1 of parent

```css
.box {
  width: 960px;
  position: relative;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  background: 0, 0, 0, 0.5;
  padding: 30px 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore blanditiis veniam autem repellat consequatur hic magnam, molestiae debitis doloremque quam
  </div>
</div>
```

When I am using the padding for content div it overflows it's parent. By the way I must use the `width:100%;` for `#content` because  I want the padding in the content div because I'm using background color for it so, how can I fix it?

Here is the [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emRPOB)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
*{box-sizing: border-box}
```

here is the Demo

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
:root{
  padding-top: 40px
}
.box{
  width:480px;
  position:relative;
}
#content{
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background:yellow;
  background:0,0,0,0.5;
  padding:30px 20%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box">
     <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore blanditiis veniam autem repellat consequatur hic magnam, molestiae debitis doloremque quam
       </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `position:relative` ...

Comment: The question explicitly asks for a solution using `position: absolute`. I had the same problem and my `div` styling is done by a layout library, so using relative positions is not possible.